# Turn array of objects into date-sorted array of objects

Tags: typescript

I have to turn an array of objects that look this this:

```js
[
  { 
    "id": 15, 
    "log_name": "default", 
    "description": "updated", 
    "properties": "{\"message\":{\"old\":\"It's 2022! Wow!\",\"new\":\"It's 2022!\"}}",                 
    "created_at": "2022-01-05 19:05:12", 
    "updated_at": "2022-01-05 19:05:12" 
  }
]
```

into something like this, sorted by descending date order:

```js
[
  {
    date: 2022-01-05,
    logs: [ array of log objects from that day ]
  },
  {
    date: 2022-01-04,
    logs: [ array of log objects from that day ]
  },
]
```

The code I came up with is really ugly and I could use some help, as I loop through the objects three times.

- First, I create an object with dates as the key and arrays of logs as the value
- Then, I convert this object into an array of objects
- Then, I sort of the array by date.

Is there a way to build that final array by only going through the array once?

````
const groupLogsByDate = (logs: ActivityLog[]): { date: string, logs: ActivityLog[] }[] => {
  const groupedLogs: {[date: string]: ActivityLog[]} = {};
  Object.values(logs).forEach((log) => {
    const date: string = log.created_at.substring(0, 10);
    if (date in groupedLogs) {
      groupedLogs[date].push(log);
    } else {
      const newDate: ActivityLog[] = [];
      groupedLogs[date] = newDate;
      groupedLogs[date].push(log);
    }
  });

  const groupedArray: {date: string, logs: ActivityLog[]}[] = [];
  Object.entries(groupedLogs).forEach(([key, val]) => {
    const obj = {
      date: key,
      logs: val,
    };
    groupedArray.push(obj);
  });

  // sort the array by date string in descending order
  groupedArray.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.date < b.date) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (b.date > a.date) {
      return -1;
    }

    return 0;
  });

  return groupedArray;
};
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three steps, and the following suggestion brings it down to two.

You've written:

- group logs by date
- for each log in each log group, add a date field from the log group
- sort all the log groups

Instead you could do:

- group logs by date, adding a date field as you process the log
- sort all the log groups

```
  const groupedLogs: {[date: string]: { date: string, logs: ActivityLog[]}} = {};
  Object.values(logs).forEach((log) => {
    const date: string = log.created_at.substring(0, 10);
    groupedLogs[date] = groupedLogs[date] || { date, logs: [] };
    groupedLogs[date].logs.push(log);
  });

  const groupedArray: {date: string, logs: ActivityLog[]}[] = Object.values(groupedLogs);
```

Regarding this expression: `groupedLogs[date] || { date, logs: [] }`

If `groupedLogs[date]` is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), then that value is used. If it is falsy, then we effectively get `false || { date, logs: [] }` which evaluates to `{ date, logs: [] }`. Effectively, this means "if it already exists, use `groupedLogs[date]`, otherwise use a new object with a value `{ date, logs: [] }`. So if there are already logs, they're left unchanged, or if there's no value then it's initialized with an empty logs list and the date.

Comment: This is a great, clean solution. Exactly what I was looking for. I actually didn't know you could assign using the `||` operator on the right-hand side. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The functions `collect` and `groupBy` will do this:

```
import { groupBy } from 'fp-ts/NonEmptyArray';
import { collect } from 'fp-ts/Record';
import { Ord } from 'fp-ts/string';

const arranged = collect(Ord)((date, logs) => ({ date, logs }))(
  groupBy(({ created_at }) => created_at.substring(0, 10))(data)
);
```